# Not counting right?

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, switch-statement

I'm trying to get this to count and collect information for different variables using a switch statement however it only counts up to 4.

I know I can do this easier with a array.

Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class WeekThreeLab
{
    static void Main()
    {
        String name, city;
        Double Drating;
        Double Judge1;
        Double Judge2;
        Double Judge3;
        Double Judge4;
        Double Judge5;
        Judge1 = 0;
        Judge2 = 0;
        Judge3 = 0;
        Judge4 = 0;
        Judge5 = 0;

        System.Console.Write("What is the drivers name: ");
        name = System.Console.ReadLine();
        System.Console.Write("What is the drivers city: ");
        city = System.Console.ReadLine();
        System.Console.Write("What is the degree of difficulty: ");
        Drating = Double.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine());
        while (Drating <= 0.99 || Drating >= 1.68)
        {
            Console.Write("Invalid! Try again! Degree of difficulty: ");
            Drating = Double.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine());
        }

        for (int count = 0; count <= 4; count++)
        {
            switch (count)
            {
                case 1:
                    System.Console.Write("Judge #{0} and his score? ", count);
                    Judge1 = Double.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine());
                    while (Judge1 < 0 || Judge1 > 10)
                    {
                        System.Console.Write("Invalid range! Reenter, Judge #{0}: ", count);
                        Judge1 = Double.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine());
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.Console.Write("Judge #{0} and his score? ", count);
                    Judge2 = Double.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine());
                    while (Judge2 < 0 || Judge2 > 10)
                    {
                        System.Console.Write("Invalid range! Reenter, Judge #{0}: ", count);
                        Judge2 = Double.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine());
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.Console.Write("Judge #{0} and his score? ", count);
                    Judge3 = Double.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine());
                    while (Judge3 < 0 || Judge3 > 10)
                    {
                        System.Console.Write("Invalid range! Reenter, Judge #{0}: ", count);
                        Judge2 = Double.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine());
                    }
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.Console.Write("Judge #{0} and his score? ", count);
                    Judge4 = Double.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine());
                    while (Judge4 < 0 || Judge4 > 10)
                    {
                        System.Console.Write("Invalid range! Reenter, Judge #{0}: ", count);
                        Judge4 = Double.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine());
                    }
                    break;
                case 5:
                    System.Console.Write("Judge #{0} and his score? ", count);
                    Judge1 = Double.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine());
                    while (Judge5 < 0 || Judge5 > 10)
                    {
                        System.Console.Write("Invalid range! Reenter, Judge #{0}: ", count);
                        Judge5 = Double.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine());
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        System.Console.WriteLine(Judge1);
        System.Console.WriteLine(Judge2);
        System.Console.WriteLine(Judge3);
        System.Console.WriteLine(Judge4);
        System.Console.WriteLine(Judge5);
        System.Console.WriteLine(" ");
        System.Console.WriteLine("Your diver: {0} ");
        System.Console.WriteLine("From the city: {0} ");
        System.Console.WriteLine("Had a final score of: {0} ");
        System.Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

Comment: If you paste code into the editor, you can use the `{}` button to format it as code.  There will be a little 'help' link next to the text area as well.  I think you can use the tags <pre> and <code> as well.

Comment: In your `for`-loop `count` will never reach 5. This is why `case 5:` never triggers.

Comment: You should consider using `double[] judge = new double[5];`instead of `Judge1` to `Judge5` as this is a classic example of the [Loop-Switch-Antipattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-switch_sequence)

Comment: @ThomasSchremser Yes I know, however that's how I have to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop counts from 0 to four, but the `switch` checks the values 1 to 5.  To include all 5 judges, change the for loop to:

```
for (int count = 1; count <= 5; count++)
```

Comment: Tried that Mike, it gives me strange outputs then (like I put in 1,2,3,4,5 for all 5 judges) and it spits out 5,2,3,4,0

Comment: when I use 0 to 4 it works fine until I get to 4 then it stops

Comment: @Chrono That would be because you use inconsistent variables in the case as well.  look at cases 3 and 5.

Comment: I'd totally vote you up if I had 15 reputation!

Comment: @Chrono You can still mark it as answer, even without reputation.

Comment: @Dominik where is that...I just got on this site...I know barely nothing about it.

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
this => for (int count = 0; count <= 5; count++){..}
```

and in the fifth case you are setting the judge1 variable:

```
Judge1 = Double.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine());
```

Change that to

```
Judge5 = Double.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine());
```